# VSCode not suggesting ES6 imports?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, es6-modules

When I'm typing the import statement I get suggestions:
[image]

However, when I move the mouse over the undefined function, I only get the following:

> "'setMouseHijack' is not defined. (W117)jshint(W117)"

Without any suggested import.

Am I missing something?
Isn't VSCode supposed to suggest me the improvement when I move the mouse over those undefined variables/functions if available to import?

[image]

The "Quick fix" won't suggest the import either:
[image]

Comment: Ok, I got it working 1 min after the bounty...  ;D

Comment: I added `//@ts-check` too a the very beginning of the file.

Comment: You can still [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) it :-)

Comment: @Alvaro please self-answer this or close your question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up solving it by enabling the `checkJS` flag in VSCode's settings.

[image]

Also on the `jsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": { 
        "checkJs": true,
    },
    "updateImportsOnFileMove": "prompt",
    "include": ["js/**/*"],
}
```